# Clue for the Treasure Hunter

Tags: logical-deduction

One day a treasure hunter was searching for treasure on an abandoned island. He got tired of looking everywhere, so he walked towards a big tree that he saw in order to rest in its shade.

As he approached the tree, he saw a board hanging on the tree. This was written on the board:

> PETS A

He understood that it was a clue and he found the treasure.

Now where was the treasure, and how did he know where to look?

Comment: This sign discriminates against giant, half-giant, ogre, dwarf, gnome and pixie treasure hunters. Booo!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The treasure was buried one step backwards from the sign.

The sign was a riddle. "PETS A" is "A STEP" backwards, and so the sign means "a step backwards".

Comment: Could also be a step to the left of the sign, although which left (facing toward or away) would be ambiguous

Comment: @Joe But the other clue is that it was written backwards, so the step must be made backwards.

Comment: It's also written right-to-left, hence "a step / to the left"

Comment: @Joe Perhaps, but if it was a step to the right, would it have been written normally?  No, I think it makes more sense to see it as simply backwards.

Comment: A step backwards('pets a' is 'a step' written 'backwards') is the right answer. So he put a step backward and dug that place.

Comment: The inverse doesn't have to be true for it to be valid. If you want to get picky on that though, if it was a step behind the sign would it be written forwards. I'm not saying that "backwards" isn't the canonical answer (it is), just that "to the left" is another valid interpretation

Comment: So let's say he dug a circle of 1 step radius around the tree and found the treasure. :P

Comment: @AeJey But that is not efficient.  It could be a big tree, the ground hard to dig.  No, the puzzle should have one solution.

Comment: @doppelgreener what makes you think he can't try multiple places? You put forth that option yourself: "I'd just dig up the base of the whole tree". If you want to break an abstraction to say that he needs to know *exactly* where the treasure is, then let's break another abstraction to say he has the ability to search the whole area around the tree.